# r shiny rhandsontable: create empty table for copy & paste of data

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I try to use rhandsontable to build a shiny app.
When running the app at first an empty table should be rendered which then could be filled with data by copy & paste. After pasting the data a plot of the values should be rendered.
My code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)

X = c("","","")
Y = c("","","")

daten = data.table(X, Y)

ui <- fluidPage(

  rHandsontableOutput("tabelle"),

  plotOutput("grafik")
 )

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactiveValues(values=daten)

  output$tabelle <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$values)
  })

  observeEvent(input$tabelle, {
    data$values <- hot_to_r(input$tabelle)
  })

  output$grafik <- renderPlot({
    if(is.null(data$values)) return(NULL)
    plot(data$values)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The app works but gives the error message

```
Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values
```

in the console and shows an error message in the browser window:

[Error: need finite 'xlim' values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAorz.png)

The error message disappears when pasting data into the table.
I think the error is due to missing data when the plot function is called the first time. At github I found the advice to add

```
if(is.null(data$values)) return(NULL)
```

in the renderPlot function but unfortunately this didn't help.
I would be very happy if anybody could help me to create an empty table with rhandsontable which could be filled with data by copy & paste.

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked this question quite some time ago, but since there is no solution provided so far, let me propose one.

To reply to your main question: Why you are getting the error message 
`Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values`?

The answer is: because you ask `R` to plot something without values. You test for `if(is.null(data$values))`. This could be a solution. However, you set `data$values <- hot_to_r(input$tabelle)`. Hence, it is NOT `NULL`.

May I suggest to alter your code as follows (not least because the usage of `data` for your input values is misleading given that `data` is an inbuilt `R` function):

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)

X <- c("", "", "")
Y <- c("", "", "")

daten <- data.table(X, Y)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput(outputId = "tabelle"),
  plotOutput(outputId = "grafik")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  data.in <- reactiveValues(values = daten)
  output$tabelle <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data.in$values)
  })

  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$tabelle, {
    data.in$values <- hot_to_r(input$tabelle)
    output$grafik <- renderPlot({
      if(!is.null(tryCatch(plot(data.in$values), error = function(e){})))
        {plot(data.in$values)}
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

`tryCatch` allows you to evaluate the expression, check if an error occurs, if yes then `error = function(e){}` drops `NULL` and nothing happens, if not then there will be a plot.